# Windows 8 re-install disk won't work with new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

I bought a new Hitachi internal hard drive for my Sony Vaio SVE151J11M Windows 8 laptop as my previous one is fried, and they are the exact same model.  I also had to purchase online a Windows 8 recovery/re-install disk.  I have put the new hard drive into the laptop, and it say's "Operating System not detected".

But when I put the Windows 8 recovery/re-install disk in it seems like the disk drive won't read it, nothing at all happens. Any help on this would be a great help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you configured BIOS to boot from CD/DVD?

Comment: I thought I would have to do that, but the BIOS message/key does not show on start up.

Comment: Have you tried searching the manual for that?

Comment: I got it, I pressed the assist key while on shut down, and it redirected me to the bios where I had to change the bios setting to legacy. everything is working now. thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, that was easy.